# Apache Archiva: how do I edit Artifact information?

Tags: maven, archiva

Is there a way for edit the Arfifact information (name, description, etc.) and the information about the *version* of an Artifact (dependencies, etc.) using the **Web interface** of Apache Archiva?

So without editing the pom.xml file directly.

Answer (score 0):

Those informations come from the pom so they cannot be edited manually.